# How do I enable fill out in a pdf file?

Tags: files, pdf

I can not fill in a pdf file. I checked file-properties-security and it appears that the fill in and sign option are not permitted.  It is also written as security method NO METHOD. I do not understand how can the fill in and sign in option be not permitted if there is no security method in place. I do not know how to make the fields fillable. Could you help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe LibreOffice Draw can make PDF forms editable so they can be completed and returned as PDFs - no need to print/scan etc. There was an article about it in the UK Linux Format magazine last month:  https://linuxformat.com/archives?issue=244 but I imagine there will be other guides on the web too.